# Notation about sets and probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let $p \to \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ be a function and $X$ a pointprocess on $S=\mathbb{R}^d$. Then
    \begin{align}
  X_{\mathrm{thin}} = \lbrace u\in X \mid R(u)\leq p(u) \rbrace \subseteq X
 \end{align}

is an independent thinning of $X$, with retention probability $p(u)$ where ${R(u) \sim \mathrm{Uniform} \left[ 0,1 \right]}$, $u\in S$, are mutually independent and independent of $X$.

Why is the following true?:

[image]

Comment: How is $X_{\mathrm{thin}}$ defined?

Comment: I've edited it, so hopefully it's a bit more clear now. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is true because the union of the sets on each side are equal. Using the fact that $X_{\text{thin}} \subseteq X$ and beginning with the union of the sets on the LHS:

\begin{eqnarray*}
(X_{\text{thin}}\cap A)\;\cup\; (X\setminus X_{\text{thin}}\cap B) &=& (X_{\text{thin}}\cap A\setminus B)\;\cup\; (X_{\text{thin}}\cap A\cap B) \\
&& \cup\;\;(X\setminus X_{\text{thin}}\cap B\setminus A) \;\cup\; (X\setminus X_{\text{thin}}\cap A\cap B) \\
&& \qquad\qquad\text{(splitting each of the two terms into two parts)} \\&& \\
&=& (X_{\text{thin}}\cap A\setminus B)\;\cup\; (X\cap A\cap B)\; \cup\;(X\setminus X_{\text{thin}}\cap B\setminus A) \\
&& \qquad\qquad\text{(combining the second and fourth terms)} \\
&& \\
&=& \text{union of the sets on the RHS.}
\end{eqnarray*}

A Venn diagram might help you visualise what's going on here.